# How is the cost of buying missing Gold with Gems calculated in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

I've recently been trying to figure out how exactly "Buy missing Gold with Gems" works.

I calculated some values by wasting my Gold on cards I don't use, and it looks like the Gold/Gems value gets better the more Gems you buy, and they never get better than the deals in store (22,22 Gold per Gem, 100.000 Gold for 4.500 Gems).

One more thing I came upon when I was testing around was that when I only needed 14 Gold, it asked to "Buy 16 Gold?" instead of "Buy missing Gold?" and sold me 16 Gold for 1 Gem, leaving 2 in my Gold balance after the upgrade. For comparison, the value is much worse than 16 Gold per Gem when I needed 18 Gold, which cost me 2 Gems.

I would love some help figuring out the exact calculation to get how many Gems are needed for x amount of Gold.